# Do tensors represent inner vector spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces, tensors

First of all let me apologize if what I am asking is way wrong or doesn't make sense. I am not a mathematician, but I'm trying to model what I have in mind in terms of mathematics.

The systems I have can be represented by different point in a cartesian coordinate of 4 dimensions. But then some of the points in such system can themselves be a system by themselves as if lets say at point (3, 5, 6, 1) we have another instance of the system embedded in it.

Just to make it more clear imagine a list data structure in programming where its components can be either integers or **another list** .

My question is if tensors are what is used to represent and model such configuration? If yes how, and if not, is there any other well established mathematical object that does the job?

What about Tensor Networks?

Comment: inner products on vector spaces are bilinear maps with certain conditions useful to define concepts like length, angles, areas, etc. Bilinear maps are rank 2 tensors.

Comment: It sounds like you want to talk about lists of lists (such as $[[1],[2],[1,2,3,4],[4]]$). Are there some additional restrictions you want to place (such as that the length of the lists are either one (in which case they represent "coordinates") or four ("another instance of the system"), finite or infinite nesting, etc)?

Comment: @levap It would be another instance of the system. Lets say I have a list of vectors and some of those vectors are in fact themselves another list of vectors.

Comment: @levap I assume I can represent a list of vectors with a tensor (correct me if I'm wrong pls), but don't know what to do if one of those vectors is representative of another list of vectors?

Comment: @al pal: If you have a list of vectors and some of those "vectors" are in fact lists of vectors, does it stop there or in your lists of vectors, some of the "vectors" can also be lists of vectors, etc?

Comment: @levap It can get nested into deeper levels, that is A can be a list of vectors of which for example a7 is itself a list of vectors of which lets say b3 is a list of vector, and so on.

Comment: @alpal: Well, I don't think tensors are natural for what you describe. You can model your "list of lists" as rooted labeled trees with the leaves marked by integers. So $x \rightarrow [1,2,y\rightarrow[1,3],z\rightarrow[1,2,3,4]]$ would be a tree with root $x$ which has four children, two of them are leaves $(1,2)$ and two of them are vertices which themselves have children so this would correspond to $[1,2,[1,3],[1,2,3,4]]$. But there are many other options. It really depends on what you want to do with your model.

Comment: @levap Thanks for your hint. And what about Tensor Networks? Would they help to have nested tensors? Or generally can we have nested tensors at all?

Comment: I don't know anything about Tensor Networks, sorry.